# Measurable structure on the space of probability measures

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

My advisor only half-jokingly mentioned that sometimes people like to consider the measurable structure on $P(X)$ where X is a locally compact polish space and $P(.)$ denotes the probability measures with the topology of distributional convergence. (Which is the same as a weak * topology as seen through Riesz Representation.)  People then consider $P^n(X)$.

I have also seen other sources defining the measurable structure on $P(X)$ not by referring to the topology and saying it's borel, but rather choosing the smallest $\sigma$ field so that all of the maps $\theta \mapsto \theta(A)$ as $A$ varies over the Borel subsets of $X$ are measurable.  My question is why this is equivalent to the description where you take the $\sigma$ field to be the Borel of the weak* topology, i.e. the topology with the notion of convergence $\theta_n \rightarrow \theta$ if and only if $\forall f$ bounded continuous on $X$ we have $\int f d\theta_n \rightarrow \int f d\theta$. (I am talking about this as if it's a weak * topology and using Riesz representation because this notion is equivalent to requiring it only for those $f$ which are vanishing at infinity.)

If it is not true for $X$ as general as I've stated, then please explain why it is true for $\mathbb{R}=X$, if it is.

Progress so far: Seeing that the borel description makes the family of maps $\theta \mapsto \theta(A)$ measurable, hence the borel description contains the other one.  This was done by seeing that $A$ can actually just range over open sets, and then approximating the indicator of open sets pointwise by continuous functions.  Also, I know that $P(X)$ is a compact metric space.

EDIT: I should take back that I see that $P(X)$ is a compact metric space.  It is not one in general.  If X is as I said, then is it at least locally compact Polish?  Banach Aoglu gives the metric.  Not sure how to get the other 3 required properties.

Comment: If you know that all maps $\theta\mapsto\theta(A)$ are measurable, then all maps $\theta\mapsto \int \phi d\theta$ where $\phi$ is a simple function are also measurable. But then all maps $\theta\mapsto \int f d\theta$ where $f$ is a bounded Borel bounded function are measurable, because any such $f$ is a uniform limit of simple functions.

Answer (score 0):

For a proof of the equivalence, see Proposition 7.25 on page 133 of *Stochastic Optimal Control: The Discrete-Time Case* by Bertsekas and Shreve 2007.